# Why does implicit conversion from some numeric values work but not others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

This is something that has only just started happening today for me.

If I run this:

```
select '185.37' * 2.00 
select '0.16' * 2.00
```

The first query returns this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

Where as the second query returns 0.32 as expected.

[image: Results]

[image: Messages]

This is on SQL Server 15.0.2080.9.

I know I can fix the issue by casting to decimal or numeric, but why does the error only occur for the higher numbers? And why has this only started occurring today? This query has been used as part of an ETL that we've been using without changing anything for the past few years.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Why are you using strings for numbers in the first place?

Comment: The issue is to do with how SQL Server determines the appropriate size of the required result value. It makes an incorrect assumption about the string (or more likely has a default value it always uses) because that is not a number. But then when it converts it to a number it finds the result is larger than it was expecting. Its happening for me on `11.0.7507.2` so it doesn't appear to be new behaviour. And the correct solution is not to store numbers as strings.

Comment: Note the error message is `Arithmetic overflow error...`. and not `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.` It does able to convert the string to numeric but the numeric size is same as `2.00`, so it causes on overflow. It is the same effect as assigning a numeric value that is too huge for the variable `declare @n decimal(3,2) = 185.37`

Comment: Dale K, appriciate the replies, but the question wasn't asking how to fix the issue or how the numeric data SHOULD be stored, it was asking about the behavior of implicit data conversion, and additionally why this has operated without issues for the past two years and now doesn't work, after no changes have been made to the ETL, or SQL Server database in between. The fix is easy enough for me to implement, but the point of the question is to get an understanding of why it became neccessary after all this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tries to convert your string to a `numeric(3,2)` because that's the type on the right of the multiplication<sup>1</sup>. If you can force your value to be a larger numeric type:

```
select '185.37' * (102.00 - 100.00)
```

Then it works fine (produces 370.74) because it'll now attempt to convert it to a `numeric(5,2)`.

Rather than doing it by a trick, however, I'd pick an appropriate numeric type for this and *explicitly* perform the required conversion, to better document what you want to occur:

```
select CONVERT(numeric(5,2),'185.37') * 2.00
```

---

<sup>1</sup>And it has a [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

EDIT (by Gordon Linoff):

SQL Server's use of type precedence for this purpose is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> For comparison operators or other expressions, the resulting data type will depend on the rules of data type precedence.

There might be just a little confusion because the documentation is not clear that the scale and precision of numerics is explicitly part of the type (that is, what gets converted is `numeric(3, 2)` rather than `numeric(?, ?)` with appropriate scale and precision).

Comment: . . I edited that answer to include the reason why type precedence is important here.

Answer (score 0):

For below mentioned SQL Left side is varchar datatype and right side is a numeric datatype `numeric(3,2)` .

```
select '185.37' * 2.00
```

After implicit conversion from varchar to numeric, `result data type will be numeric(3,2) but actual result 370.74 need a datatype of numeric(5,2)` so this expression fails with overflow error. you can see the datatype of these in below sample code.

```
select 2.00 as colDatatype,185.37 as colDatatype2, 370.74 as colDatatype3 into #tempdata

SELECT * FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name like'#tempdata%';
```

In such cases explicitly cast the expression to desired out datatype and not merely
depend on implicit conversion of data types. You can refer the Datatype conversion chart on the website but here result data type after implicit conversion is not know.

[Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)